# What's the most reliable way to unit-test that a Java copy constructor deep-clones all properties?

Tags: java, testing

My project contains a set of simple model classes of the form:

```java
public class Car {
    public String model = "";
    public Instant productionDate = null;
    public List<Tire> tires = new ArrayList<>();
    // ....
}

public class Tire {
    public String maker = "";
    public int size = 0;
    // ...
}

// ...
```

I want to enable deep-cloning all these classes by adding copy constructors to them, of the form:

```java
public class Car {

    public Car(Car original) {
        this.model = original.model;
        this.productionDate = original.productionDate;
        this.tires.addAll(original.tires.stream().map(tire -> new Tire(tire)).toList();
    }

}
```

This can be united tested quite easily. Simply create an object, call the copy constructor with it, then assert that the resulting object has the same property values.

However, with this unit test design I see the danger that somebody will add a field to one of the classes and forget to update the copy constructor and unit test assertions.

Is there a better way to unit test this? Maybe one that automatically compares *all* of the original and cloned objects' properties, without having to explicitly name them?

Comment: I assume you are aware that this is only really possible if none of your fields uses inheritance - the `Car` needs to 'know' the runtime type of `Tire` at compile time. For the more general case, you'd need something like a `TireFactory` that knows how to create a copy of a given tire. Deep Copying gets surprisingly complicated really quickly, unless you can restrict your object graph to be very simple.

Comment: Point taken. Our data model adheres to strict conventions. Plain old Java objects. No inheritance. In our specific setup, the deep copy should be possible. But agree that more complex setups will mean that it cannot be applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to use the [java reflection api](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html). If you haven't used it before its easy and pretty darn powerful despite it being avoided. I think testing is certainly a valid use case for it if there was one. You can iterate over all properties of your object and confirm the values in the input object match the new values in the initialized object.

This isn't without its caveats though if some fields are allowed to be null you might get a false positive as your test would check that propertyA == propertyB even though both are just null and the new field is not linked to its constructor. You can use the reflection API to set values in the test object to get around this so you could invoke your "Reflection constructor" to get the test object into the desired state, pass that into the copy constructor and validate both have matching properties and you can do this iteratively without having to know the name of the properties ahead of time.